# Show / Hide a table when a audio player is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to show / hide tables when a song on a audio player is clicked.
I would like the table to change when a different song is clicked, meaning the previous table disappears while the new one appears.

I'm using this audio player :
https://amazingaudioplayer.com/examples/responsive-html5-audio-player-with-playlist-id10/

I've tried to use Jquery but so far, it does not work :( :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingaudioplayer/sharedengine/amazingaudioplayer.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("#table").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="amazingaudioplayer-10" style="display:block;position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;margin:0px auto 0px;">
    <ul class="amazingaudioplayer-audios" style="display:none;">
        <li id="show" data-artist="pinkzebra" data-title="In The Moment of Inspiration" data-album="AudioJungle" data-info="" data-image="https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingaudioplayer/10/audios/golden-wheat-field.jpg" data-duration="154">
            <div class="amazingaudioplayer-source" data-src="https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingaudioplayer/10/audios/In the Moment of Inspiration.mp3" data-type="audio/mpeg" />
            <div class="amazingaudioplayer-source" data-src="https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingaudioplayer/10/audios/In the Moment of Inspiration.ogg" data-type="audio/ogg" />
        </li>
    <ul>
<div>
<div>
    <table id="table">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Could someone tell me if what i'm trying to do is possible using the responsive audio player ? And pinpoint what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help and answers.

Comment: where's your table element? please post the html as well

Comment: you also have 2 references to jquery. remove one of them

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've added the HTML code.
I've also removed the second reference to Jquery (1.11.3), it's not working.

Comment: Parent Ul of #show li is hidden. You have set it to display none. how are you able to click on that #show li?

Comment: Thank you King Size. Indeed, I haven't seen the "display:none" on the ul element. I've replaced it by "style="list-style:none;" but it's still not working.

Comment: why don't you just show/hide the div

Comment: @RachelGallen I've already tried this solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't work :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3054364 it should - you obviously didn't implement it correctly. Whats your website

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm working on my computer (local) not on a website for now.
I've tried this which is not working:
<div id="table">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
I've realised that it works when the "id" is outside the html code of the player, but put inside the player code, it does not work.

Comment: @user3054364 that's the desired outcome is it not? or is there something i'm missing? you're supposed to put it outside

Comment: @RachelGallen it may be clearer with this : http://jsfiddle.net/b0kag50h/ I'm talking about the "id="hide" put on the "li" tag which is inside the html player code. The other id "table" is outside. Well, when I'm testing to add another ul + li elements with another "id=hide" outside the player code, it works. So I don't know why it's not working inside the player T_T

Comment: i was just about to post a fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/g9CS5/8/

Comment: Yep @RachelGallen this way it works. But when I try to adapt this to the audio player, it does not work anymore :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b0kag50h/3/

Comment: how do you mean? are you trying to hide the audio stuff?

Comment: No @RachelGallen I want the table to disappear on click on the first song of the player (the first li tag). Then I want it to appear on click on the second song (the second li tag).

Comment: well you didn't explain that very well

Comment: Sorry @RachelGallen, I thought that "I'm trying to show / hide tables when a song on an audio player is clicked. I would like the table to change when a different song is clicked, meaning the previous table disappears while the new one appears" was clear enough :(

Comment: @user3054364 i have the answer! what you need is an accordion http://jsbin.com/copaxuhomu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @user3054364 did you try my answer?